# How to Scrape a popup using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape Ngo's data like name,mobile no,city etc from https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/search/. It has names of the NGOs in a table format and on clicking on each name gives way to a pop up page. In my code below, I'm extracting the onclick attribute for each NGO.I am making a get followed by a post request to extract the data. I've tried accessing it using selenium but the json data is not coming.

```
list_of_cells = []
for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        text = cell.text.replace("&nbsp;", "") 
        list_of_cells.append(text)
 list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
 writer=csv.writer(f)
 writer.writerow(list_of_cells)
```

By implementing above portion we can get entire details of the table of all the pages .In this website there are 7721 pages.we can simply change number_of_pages var.

But our motive is to find Ngo phone no/email id which is the main purpose we will get after clicking ngo name link.But it is not a href to link rather it a api get req followed by post request to fetch data.find in network section of inspect

```
driver.get("https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/search/") # load the web page
sleep(2)
....
....
driver.find_element(By.NAME,"commit").submit()
for page in range(number_of_pages - 1):
    list_of_rows = []
    src = driver.page_source # gets the html source of the page
    parser = BeautifulSoup(src,'html.parser') 
    sleep(1)
    table = parser.find("table",{ "class" : "table table-bordered table-striped" })
    sleep(1)
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[:]:
        list_of_cells = []
        for cell in row.find_all('td'):
                x = requests.get("https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/get_csrf")
                dat=x.json()
                z=dat["csrf_token"]
                print(z) # prints csrf token
                r= requests.post("https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/show_ngo_info", data = {'id':'','csrf_test_name':'z'})
                json_data=r.text  # i guess here is something not working it is printing html text but we need text data of post request like mob,email,and here it will print all the data .
                with open('data1.json', 'a') as outfile:
                    json.dump(json_data, outfile)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'»')]").click()
```

There is no such error message the code is running but it is printing html content

```
<html>
...
...
<body>
        <div id="container">
                <h1>An Error Was Encountered</h1>
                <p>The action you have requested is not allowed.</p>    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show a sample search, and the start of the results you are trying to extract.

Comment: My main motive is to extract mobile no or email id which is appearing after clicking the ngo name.

Comment: Your token is passed as a string `z` not the variable, try `ata = {'id':'','csrf_test_name':z}`. You would also need to pass a suitable `id`

Answer (score 1):

This could be done much faster by avoiding the use of Selenium. Their site appears to continually request a token prior to each request, you might find it is possible to skip this.

The following shows how to get the JSON containing the mobile number and email address:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

def get_token(sess):
    req_csrf = sess.get('https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/get_csrf')
    return req_csrf.json()['csrf_token']


search_url = "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/search_index_new/{}"
details_url = "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/show_ngo_info"

sess = requests.Session()

for page in range(0, 10000, 10):    # Advance 10 at a time
    print(f"Getting results from {page}")

    for retry in range(1, 10):

        data = {
            'state_search' : 7, 
            'district_search' : '',
            'sector_search' : 'null',
            'ngo_type_search' : 'null',
            'ngo_name_search' : '',
            'unique_id_search' : '',
            'view_type' : 'detail_view',
            'csrf_test_name' : get_token(sess), 
        }

        req_search = sess.post(search_url.format(page), data=data, headers={'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req_search.content, "html.parser")
        table = soup.find('table', id='example')

        if table:
            for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
                row = [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]
                link = tr.find('a', onclick=True)

                if link:
                    link_number = link['onclick'].strip("show_ngif(')")
                    req_details = sess.post(details_url, headers={'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'}, data={'id' : link_number, 'csrf_test_name' : get_token(sess)})
                    json = req_details.json()
                    details = json['infor']['0']

                    print([details['Mobile'], details['Email'], row[1], row[2]])
            break
        else:
            print(f'No data returned - retry {retry}')
            time.sleep(3)
```

This would give you the following kind of output for the first page:

```
['9871249262', 'pnes.delhi@yahoo.com', 'Pragya Network Educational Society', 'S-52559, Narela, DELHI']
['9810042046', 'mathew.cherian@helpageindia.org', 'HelpAge India', '9270, New Delhi, DELHI']
['9811897589', 'aipssngo@yahoo.com', 'All India Parivartan Sewa Samiti', 's-43282, New Delhi, DELHI']
```

Comment: For iterating over all pages it is showing error  for tr in table.find_all('tr')[:]:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: I have noticed that site sometimes does not return the correct page, they might have rate limiting enabled. You might have to test `table` for `None` and retry with a delay.

Comment: The code is noot iterating all the pages it is only printing the first page

Comment: If your code is running properly please send me on my mail it woulb be a great help sir

Comment: Correct, it was only designed to show you how to get the first page. You would need to add another loop to work your way through all pages.

Comment: akashrao96@gmail.com

Comment: Sir i have added another loop

Comment: I have posted the updated code in the below section of answers

Comment: I have added in the below section please look up once .This data is very imp to me.I am working on it for many days but can't scrape it till now

Comment: My updated code now works for multiple pages. The token needed getting for each loop.

Comment: Sir it is not iterating it is returning No data returned after extracting first page

Comment: Please make sure you have copied the latest version (refresh the page), it should work fine.

Comment: You can see it working here: [run demo](https://repl.it/repls/DrabScornfulFeeds)  Just press `Run`

Comment: I got it Very Thanks to you sir for helping me

Comment: I am trying to dump json data into a file it is showing error

Comment: It is usually just to ask one question at a time. I suggest you accept this answer (click the tick) and then start a new question regarding your JSON problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python)

> You can use an XPath to locate the :
>
> `iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='Dialogue Window']")`
>
> Then switch_to the :
>
> `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)`
>
> Here's how to switch back to the default content (out of the ):
>
> `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

In your instance, I believe the 'Dialogue Window' name would be `CalendarControlIFrame`

Once you switch to that frame, you will be able to use Beautiful Soup to get the frame's html.

Comment: where do i use this iframe?

Comment: should i use this where i am making request.get in my code

Answer (score 0):

I am tying to iterate over all the pages and extract data in one attempt
After extracting data from one page it is not iterating other pages

```
....
....

    ['9829059202', 'cecoedecon@gmail.com', 'CECOEDECON', '206, Jaipur, RAJASTHAN']
    ['9443382475', 'odamindia@gmail.com', 'ODAM', '43/1995, TIRUCHULI, TAMIL NADU']
    ['9816510096', 'shrisaisnr@gmail.com', 'OPEN EDUCATIONAL DEVELOPMENT RESEARCH AND WELFARE', '126/2004, SUNDERNAGAR, HIMACHAL PRADESH']
    ['9425013029', 'card_vivek@yahoo.com', 'Centre for Advanced Research and Development', '25634, Bhopal, MADHYA PRADESH']
    ['9204645161', 'secretary_smvm@yahoo.co.in', 'Srijan Mahila Vikas Manch', '833, Chakradharpur, JHARKHAND']
    ['9419107550', 'amarjit.randwal@gmail.com', 'J and K Sai Star Society', '4680-S, Jammu, JAMMU & KASHMIR']
    No data returned - retry 2
    No data returned - retry 2
    No data returned - retry 2
    No data returned - retry 2
    No data returned - retry 2
...
...
```